# Ebean setIncludeSoftDeletes() throw SQLException

Tags: playback, ebean, soft-delete, playframework-2.6

I have two table with @History and @SoftDelet each. When I work with non deleted data it is fine. But when I try find a deleted data for model which contains field with EAGER loading option, using setIncludeSoftDeletes():

```
t2.find.query().setId(id).setIncludeSoftDeletes().findOne();
```

I got Exception:

> Query threw SQLException:No value specified for parameter 2 Bind values:[1, ] Query was:select t0.id, t0.deleted, t1.id from t2 t0 left join t1_with_history t1 on t1.t2_id = t0.id and (t1.sys_period_start <= ? and (t1.sys_period_end is null or t1.sys_period_end > ?))  where t0.id = ?

why was added a join with view t1_with_history?

Models

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t1")
@History
public class t1 extends Model {
    public static final Finder<String, t1> find = new Finder<>(t1.class);
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @SoftDelete
    public Boolean deleted;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "t2_id")
    private t2 _t2;
    @JsonIgnore
    public t2 get_t2(){
        return this._t2;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t2")
@History
public class t2 extends Model {
    public static final Finder<String, t2> find = new Finder<>(t2.class);
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @SoftDelete
    public Boolean deleted;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "_t2", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public t1 _t1;
}
```

Comment: I didn't find any documentation for this case.

Comment: example project: https://github.com/AndreyVS/ebean-history-with-softdelet

Comment: topic on Google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/7BEJ3EQznl4